# Jquery Mobile datepicker appearing behind popup window

Tags: jquery, mobile, popup, datepicker

I have an app where users can post/request carpooling.  When you they go to create a ride, however, the datepicker is appearing behind the popup where they enter the data.

http://maplemtn.com/~spencer/ridecircle/greg/#allrides

click 'create ride'

click 'when?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following rule to your stylesheet:

```
.dw { z-index: 2000 !important; }
```